# Converter for Static Resources on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hopefully this should be an easy one, i have a background of a rectangle i want to display as the phone accent colour or a disabled color based on a boolean in my view model.

I assume that converters are the way to go, but not sure of the syntax to get access to the static resources.

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grab the code for a generic `BoolToValueConverter` from this blog article:-

[A Generic Boolean Value Converter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx)

Also include in your code this specialisation for a converter to a Brush:-

```
public class BoolToBrushConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Brush> { }
```

Now add the converter to your Xaml like this:-

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="DisabledBrushConv"
      FalseValue="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
      TrueValue="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
</Grid>
```

Then in rectangle :-

```
 <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Disabled, Converter={StaticResource DisabledBrushConv}}" ... />
```

This assumes the property in your view model is called `Disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use a [converter](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)
2. Define a property on your viewmodel that returns a Brush based on the boolean value. I would prefer this solution because the performance hit of converters are more noticable on the phone than on the desktop.